# Only the first Django site to be loaded works

Tags: python, django, apache, xampp

I recently submitted a problem to stackoverflow titled [Django infinite loading after multiple requests on apache using mod_wsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71705909/django-infinite-loading-after-multiple-requests-on-apache-using-mod-wsgi). Anyways, I have recently changed a lot of that code and now I have a new problem. The first Django website I request works, however, the second one points to the first one I loaded and gives the response DisallowedHost because obviously it is trying to access that Django application with a different domain name. I obviously want it to do that it should do so if anyone can help me that would be great. Here is all my code.

---

**EDIT:**
Using Razenstein's suggestions my websites now stall, meaning they won't load.

**EDIT #2**
I get this error every time I try connect to neostorm.us.to (my first website) [Sun Apr 03 19:26:58.563023 2022] [ssl:info] [pid 17528:tid 2116] [client 10.0.0.138:59334] AH01964: Connection to child 147 established (server astinarts.uk.to:443)

**EDIT #3**
No luck yet, I have updated my version of XAMPP with it, Apache and the problem persists. No one seems to know why this is happening. My python version if fine (3.10.4)

Vhosts

```
    LoadFile "C:/Users/taber/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python310.dll"
    LoadModule wsgi_module "C:/Users/taber/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp310-win_amd64.pyd"
    WSGIPythonHome "C:/Users/taber/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310"
    ##################################################################################################
    #                                       ASTINARTS.UK.TO VIRTUAL HOST                             #
    ##################################################################################################
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName astinarts.uk.to
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile "conf/astinarts/astinarts.uk.to-chain.pem"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/astinarts/astinarts.uk.to-key.pem"
    
    Alias /static "C:/xampp/htdocs/astinarts/static"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/astinarts/static">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    Alias /media "C:/xampp/htdocs/astinarts/media"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/astinarts/media">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    Alias /.well-known "C:/xampp/htdocs/astinarts/.well-known"
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\astinarts\.well-known">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    Alias /sitemap.xml "C:/xampp/htdocs/astinarts/sitemap.xml"
    Alias /robots.txt "C:/xampp/htdocs/astinarts/robots.txt"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/astinarts/astinarts">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/xampp/htdocs/astinarts/astinarts/wsgi.py"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/astinarts/astinarts">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
    ##################################################################################################
    #                                       NEOSTORM.US.TO VIRTUAL HOST                              #
    ##################################################################################################
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName neostorm.us.to
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/neostorm.us.to-chain.pem"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/neostorm.us.to-key.pem"
    Alias /static "C:/xampp/htdocs/neostorm/static"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/neostorm/static">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    Alias /media "C:/xampp/htdocs/neostorm/media"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/neostorm/media">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    Alias /sitemap.xml "C:/xampp/htdocs/neostorm/sitemap.xml"
    Alias /robots.txt "C:/xampp/htdocs/neostorm/robots.txt"
    WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/xampp/htdocs/neostorm/neostorm/wsgi_windows.py"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/neostorm/neostorm">
        <Files wsgi_windows.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "C:\xampp\apache\logs\neostorm_error.log"
    CustomLog "C:\xampp\apache\logs\neostorm_custom.log" common
    </VirtualHost>
    ##################################################################################################
    #                                   MAIL.NEOSTORM.US.TO VIRTUAL HOST                             #
    ##################################################################################################
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName mail.neostorm.us.to
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/neostorm.us.to-chain.pem"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/neostorm.us.to-key.pem"
        DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/webmail"
        <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/webmail">
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Site 1 WSGI file

```
    import os
    import sys
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    from pathlib import Path
    
    # Add project directory to the sys.path
    path_home = str(Path(__file__).parents[1])
    if path_home not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(path_home)
    
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'astinarts.settings'
    
    application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Site 2 WSGI file

```
    import os
    import sys
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    from pathlib import Path
    
    # Add project directory to the sys.path
    path_home = str(Path(__file__).parents[1])
    if path_home not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(path_home)
    
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'neostorm.settings'
    
    application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't having multiple websites, using mod wsgi or even using Windows. The actual problem is the database. For some reason (no idea why) the default database becomes corrupt.

The solution was for me to switch to MySQL from the default database. I'm not entirely sure why the default database becomes corrupt.

This is what you can do if you want to switch to MySQL.

Inside of your settings.py find DATABASES and make it this.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE'  : 'django.db.backends.mysql', # <-- UPDATED line 
    'NAME'    : 'DATABASE_NAME',                 # <-- UPDATED line 
    'USER'    : 'USER',                     # <-- UPDATED line
    'PASSWORD': 'PASSWORD',              # <-- UPDATED line
    'HOST'    : 'localhost',                # <-- UPDATED line
    'PORT'    : '3306',
}
}
```

See this for more information: Django website fails to load after request

Answer (score 0):

Note: i do not know if the behavior below is for all versions of mod_wsgi the same and if the bug has been fixed. I observed it in 2020/2021 in Windows. Versions I cant remember. It never appeared in Ubuntu environment.

If you use virt hosts in Windows Apache with mod_wsgi and define the App..Group %{GLOBAL} always the WSGIApplication in the first(!!) virt. host will be called whatever ServerName etc. fits. That must be a bug in mod_wsgi or Apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName my_server_one.com
    ....
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    ....
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName my_server_two.com
    ....
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    ....
</VirtualHost>
```

Solution: use individual explicit Group names:

```
    
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName my_server_one.com
    ....
    WSGIApplicationGroup my_app_one
    ....
</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName my_server_two.com
    ....
    WSGIApplicationGroup my_app_two
    ....
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I implemented your solution and now the Django sites aren't responding, its an endless loop of loading.

Comment: What is in error.log and access.log?

Comment: There is nothing in my error.log and access.log, I also configured everything for my venv, however, it hasn't fixed anything.

Comment: Please start apache from command line as httpd and check messages on the console

Comment: There are no errors when I stop and start Apache.

Comment: set "LogLevel info" in httpd.conf and add a print statement in wsgi.py like "print('**** in app_name wsgi.py ****') and post the content of error.log

Comment: I get this error every time I try connect to neostorm.us.to (my first website) [Sun Apr 03 19:26:58.563023 2022] [ssl:info] [pid 17528:tid 2116] [client 10.0.0.138:59334] AH01964: Connection to child 147 established (server astinarts.uk.to:443)