# Django website fails to load after request

Tags: python, django

I have two Django websites on the same server using Apache (windows 10) with mod_wsgi. My first Django website runs fine, it is a lot simpler, my second one, however, does not. Once I connect to it, it loads very slowly, however, I can't connect to it again (it just remains in
the connecting phase with no errors). I've had this problem for quite a while, here are my other posts for context.

- [Only the first Django site to be loaded works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71723679/only-the-first-django-site-to-be-loaded-works)
- [Django infinite loading after multiple requests on apache using mod_wsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71705909/django-infinite-loading-after-multiple-requests-on-apache-using-mod-wsgi)
- [Django websites not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71792554/django-websites-not-loading)

**EDIT:**
**I can confirm the error is definitely in the Mainfront (front app) views.py, but I have no idea why.** This is my index.html, If I remove {% %} and its contents, the problem goes away, any ideas?

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
      {% for instance in object_list %}
      <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <span class="author card-header float-right">Posted by {{ instance.user }}, {{ instance.created_at }}</span>
        <h2 style="color: black;" class="card-title font-weight-bold text-uppercase">{{ instance.title }}</h2>
          {{ instance.body|safe }}  
      </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

DEBUG:

```
(0.000) SELECT "mainfront_article"."id", "mainfront_article"."title", "mainfront_article"."body", "mainfront_article"."created_at", "mainfront_article"."user_id" FROM "mainfront_article" ORDER BY "mainfront_article"."created_at" DESC; args=(); alias=default
(0.000) SELECT "mainfront_article"."id", "mainfront_article"."title", "mainfront_article"."body", "mainfront_article"."created_at", "mainfront_article"."user_id" FROM "mainfront_article" ORDER BY "mainfront_article"."created_at" DESC; args=(); alias=default
(0.000) SELECT "mainfront_article"."id", "mainfront_article"."title", "mainfront_article"."body", "mainfront_article"."created_at", "mainfront_article"."user_id" FROM "mainfront_article" ORDER BY "mainfront_article"."created_at" DESC; args=(); alias=default
(0.000) SELECT "mainfront_article"."id", "mainfront_article"."title", "mainfront_article"."body", "mainfront_article"."created_at", "mainfront_article"."user_id" FROM "mainfront_article" ORDER BY "mainfront_article"."created_at" DESC; args=(); alias=default
(0.000) SELECT "mainfront_article"."id", "mainfront_article"."title", "mainfront_article"."body", "mainfront_article"."created_at", "mainfront_article"."user_id" FROM "mainfront_article" ORDER BY "mainfront_article"."created_at" DESC; args=(); alias=default
(0.000) SELECT "mainfront_article"."id", "mainfront_article"."title", "mainfront_article"."body", "mainfront_article"."created_at", "mainfront_article"."user_id" FROM "mainfront_article" ORDER BY "mainfront_article"."created_at" DESC; args=(); alias=default
(0.000) SELECT "mainfront_article"."id", "mainfront_article"."title", "mainfront_article"."body", "mainfront_article"."created_at", "mainfront_article"."user_id" FROM "mainfront_article" ORDER BY "mainfront_article"."created_at" DESC; args=(); alias=default
```

Only quite recently have I pinpointed the problem to this specific Django project, I will provide most of my code below. Hopefully, someone can show me what I have done wrong. Contact me if this isn't enough information, thank you.

Base urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("accounts/", include("accounts.urls")),
    path('', include('mainfront.urls')),
    path('about/', include('mainfront.urls')),
    path('contact/', include('mainfront.urls')),
    path('home/', include('mainfront.urls')),
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
]
```

Base WSGI

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

import sys

sys.path.append('C:/xampp/htdocs/neostorm')

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'neostorm.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Mainfront (front app) views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import threading
from mcstatus import JavaServer
from .models import Article
#Query the minecraft server every 5 seconds
def queryserver():
    threading.Timer(5.0, queryserver).start()
    server = JavaServer.lookup("neostorm.us.to:25565")
    try:
        global status 
        server.status().latency
        global playersonline 
        playersonline = server.status().players.online
    except:
        status='Offline'
        playersonline='n/a'
    else:
        status='Online'
queryserver()
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    #Sort Article class by date of created date and updated date
    obj = Article.objects.order_by('-created_at')[:10]
    article_context = {
        "object_list":obj
    }
    return render(request, 'mainfront/index.html', {'playeronline' : playersonline, 'status' : status} | article_context)

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'mainfront/About.html')

def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'mainfront/Contact.html')
```

Mainfront models.py

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



# Create your models here.
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)
    #Order the articles model by the date of update
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
```

Settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for neostorm project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path, os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'fdsy874ybfrdeouit6487t64986483699676966nope'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['neostorm.us.to', '127.0.0.1']

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'C:/xampp/htdocs/neostorm/debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'mainfront', #front page (home, about and contact)
]
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'articles/'
CKEDITORBackGround = '#7D001D'
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'skin': 'moono-lisa',
        'toolbar_Basic': [
            ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic']
        ],
        'toolbar_YourCustomToolbarConfig': [
            {'name': 'document', 'items': ['Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates']},
            {'name': 'clipboard', 'items': ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo']},
            {'name': 'editing', 'items': ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll']},
            {'name': 'forms',
             'items': ['Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton',
                       'HiddenField']},
            '/',
            {'name': 'basicstyles',
             'items': ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat']},
            {'name': 'paragraph',
             'items': ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-',
                       'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl',
                       'Language']},
            {'name': 'links', 'items': ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor']},
            {'name': 'insert',
             'items': ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe']},
            '/',
            {'name': 'styles', 'items': ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']},
            {'name': 'colors', 'items': ['TextColor', 'BGColor']},
            {'name': 'tools', 'items': ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks']},
            '/',  # put this to force next toolbar on new line
            {'name': 'yourcustomtools', 'items': [
                # put the name of your editor.ui.addButton here
                'Preview',
                'Maximize',

            ]},
        ],
        'toolbar': 'YourCustomToolbarConfig',  # put selected toolbar config here
        # 'toolbarGroups': [{ 'name': 'document', 'groups': [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] }],
        # 'height': 291,
        # 'width': '100%',
        # 'filebrowserWindowHeight': 725,
        # 'filebrowserWindowWidth': 940,
        # 'toolbarCanCollapse': True,
        # 'mathJaxLib': '//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.2-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML',
        'tabSpaces': 4,
        'extraPlugins': ','.join([
            'uploadimage', # the upload image feature
            # your extra plugins here
            'div',
            'autolink',
            'autoembed',
            'embedsemantic',
            'autogrow',
            'widget',
            'lineutils',
            'clipboard',
            'dialog',
            'dialogui',
            'elementspath'
        ]),
    }
}
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'neostorm.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'neostorm.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Australia/Melbourne'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = "images/"

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Comment: I would definitely install the django debug toolbar to see what is causing the slowdown. https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @sipi09 the problem is with my for statement, I think it keeps looping on nothing and causes the whole thing to go down the sh**er. Please read the entire post, especially my edits

Comment: I wonder why you pass the "object_list":obj in article_context in the way you do it? Wouldn't it be enough to pass it as similar to the other context element, so like this: return render(request, 'mainfront/index.html', {'playeronline' : playersonline, 'status' : status, 'object_list' : obj} )

Comment: @sipi09 I agree, that is a bit quirky, but it doesn't resolve any issues if I change because it is two methods with the same result.

Comment: Your query "obj = Article.objects.order_by('-created_at')[:10]" only gets actually executed when you use it in the for loop of your template. Before it does not hit the date base. So most certainly the database access and what you are doing with threading conflicts and creates the blocking. I would run the app without queryserver() and see if the blocking is gone. That would explain why removing the for loop avoids the problem. Next step search for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was for me to switch to MySQL from the default database. I'm not entirely sure why the default database becomes corrupt.

This is what you can do if you want to switch to MySQL.

Inside of your settings.py find DATABASES and make it this.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE'  : 'django.db.backends.mysql', # <-- UPDATED line 
    'NAME'    : 'DATABASE_NAME',                 # <-- UPDATED line 
    'USER'    : 'USER',                     # <-- UPDATED line
    'PASSWORD': 'PASSWORD',              # <-- UPDATED line
    'HOST'    : 'localhost',                # <-- UPDATED line
    'PORT'    : '3306',
}
```

}

Comment: this answer doesn't very well apply to this users specific question, or if it does, the answer doesn't make clear how.

Comment: @silverdagger Is this a better solution?

Comment: Yeah that helps a bit.